# CSS element updates at the end of long JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, css, ajax

I am running a js function that uses ajax to query an ldap server to retrieve multiple user information and input to a mysql db. This is done by looping an ldap request with different parameters each time.

Because the ldap server is slow to respond I am adding in a progress bar. Every time a query is completed, it triggers an update to the progress bar. The problem is the progress bar only updates once after the entire function has been completed, even though the CSS update happens before the loop even starts.

```js
function findUsers() {
  //set Number of users
  var noOfUsers = 10;
  var progress = 1;

  //progress bar div appears as soon as function begins
  //this element change doesn't happen till the function has finsihed
  document.getElementById('progress_bar').style.visibility = 'visible';


  //loop through users
  for (counter = 0; counter <= noOfUsers; counter++) {
    //update element with progress
    document.getElementById('progress_bar').innerHTML = progress + " of " + noOfUsers;

    //start AJAX
    xhrPostUserIDToLDAP = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhrPostUserIDToLDAP.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xhrPostUserIDToLDAP.readyState == 4 && xhrPostUserIDToLDAP.status == 200) {
        //updates progress var so on next loop, the element is updated
        progress++;
      }
    }
    xhrPostEmployees.open("POST", "ajax/ldap.php", false);
    xhrPostEmployees.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhrPostEmployees.send("userID=" + userID);
  }
  //loop has finsihed, update element with complete notification
  document.getElementById('progress_bar').innerHTML = "Completed";
}
```

The only thing that the element is updated with is Completed, but this happens after 20 seconds once the function is completed.

How do I update the element as the loop cycles?

Comment: I should mention this script is heavily edited from the real one, it's not clear our the User Id enters this function... but it's irrelevant to the code in this example.. just use your imagination :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are quickly looping through the loop and making 10 *asynchronous  requests*.  Each time you go through the loop, it sets `progress_bar` using `progress`. Since the callbacks haven't fired or returned from the server, `progress` is always equal to one.  To fix this, you need to put:

```
document.getElementById('progress_bar').innerHTML = progress + " of " + noOfUsers;
```

Inside of your `onreadystatechange` callback after you do `progress++`.  This ensures that after the each asynchronous request comes back to the server, you update `progress_bar`.

Comment: So I had a synchronous request instead of asynchronous, I have changed that now and the visibility works when the function starts. But even with the progress_bar update in the onreadystatechange it doesn't update till the end of the function.

Comment: There has to be some other issue going on then.  As far as your source goes, my answer should have fixed it.  Have you tried using chrome or FF and putting a breakpoint in and watching the code?